# Case - Reopening of a case

Tags: permissions, case

Currently in our SFDC Case only administrators will be able to reopen a case.

But some of our users want this privilege (ability to reopen a case) too.

Can someone tell me how this can be done in Salesforce ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about dropping into the relevant **Profile** and enabling `Manage Cases` permission?

[image: manage-cases]

You could also create a **Permission Set** with the same, and assign that to the relevant users.

[image: permission-set]

Comment: All of the Case users have the same profile though.We want only a subset of the users to have this privilege.

Comment: @RisingPhoenix how about creating a Permission Set and assigning that more sparingly?

Comment: Is there any way to more than one user at the same timeto the permission set ?.I have like 130 users to add :(.Kinda difficult to add one by one

Comment: You could use Developer Console to insert `PermissionSetAssignment` records, or use an AppExchange package like the _Permissioner_ @RisingPhoenix